# Akka Http JSON serialization is very slow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray, spray-json

I'm measuring 3-4 ms serialization time of simple JSON. Is this the performance to expect from AKKA or is there something that can be done to rectify it?

```
case class Response(msg: String)
implicit val format = jsonFormat(Response)


def logMagnet()(t: LoggingAdapter): HttpRequest => RouteResult => Unit = {
    request => {
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
      response => {
        val total = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        logger.info("took $total")
      }
    }
  }

val route = logRequestResult(LoggingMagnet(logMagnet())) {
   val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
   val calculateSomethings = ....
   val duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
   val response = Response("took $duration to calculate")
   complete(response)
}
```

The time between the logged and the response is 3-4 ms consistantly for trivial serializations.

Comment: Since you haven't used something like JMH for benchmark I can assume that this is probably just a cold-JVM - in other words you would have to run this code many times over (let's say 100-1000 times) to simulate actual workload, where JVM optimizations kick-in.

Comment: And which JSON serialization you used? Vanilla Akka-HTTP doesn't have any JSON serialization build-in as far as I remember, you would have to use some Spray/Play JSON or Circe or sth else.

Comment: Are you testing a single request?

Comment: long running, also tested with JMeter and AB, using spray marshaling

Comment: I'd suggest to use json4s, and do not use curentTimeMillis. You didn't provide the code for 'calculateSomething'. It  might be the slowest part of your code.

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with what you are saying. the response message is the time that the "calculate something" took, the measured time from the Akka perspective is much higher due to it's implementation details , possibly of the serialization, but possible just because it is horrible